# Clustering algorithms that support FA rather than PCA

Tags: r, k-means, factor-analysis

In our social sci research we've used Factor Analysis rather than PCA.  It would be helpful for us to use a clustering algorithm to group respondents into the most logical factor groups.  Kmeans seems to use PCA as the basis for its clustering.

1. Is there a way to specify `factoextra::kmeans()` or other package to use FA rather than PCA?
2. Which clustering algorithms would support FA?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. There doesn't seem to be a `factoextra::kmeans` function. There is a `stats::kmeans` function. Where did you see that `kmeans` uses PCA? But general discussions about clustering algorithms would be a better fit for [stats.se] rather than Stack Overflow. There doesn't really seem to by any R-specific issue here and there is no code or data to actually test with.

Comment: You can do cluster analysis like K-means on any quantitative variables. It could be original variables, PCA scores or Factor scores.